# access to local web site from internet using hostname

Tags: internet, openwrt, lan

I've got a server on my LAN which hosts a website. I've also got a router with openWRT serving as gate between the internet (with public IP 1.2.3.4) and LAN and a registered hostname say "myhost.com". I could set additional subhost gitlab.myhost.com pointing to 1.2.3.4.

The question is: how do I pass connections to LAN (via the openWRT router) using port 80 or 443 only when the request is for gitlab.myhost.com.

Comment: I don't think it's clear what you're asking. Could you clarify please? The way I understand your question is: you have a webserver on your LAN and you'd like to make it publicly available to the internet. Is that right or am I confusing something?

Comment: yes it is. but i want to do it most securely.

Comment: Do you have a public IP?

Comment: yes i'm. My router (not a server with a site) have a public IP (maybe I mistakenly called it the "white")